# Ng-repeat of json data in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using Angular JS to retrieve some data with JSON. With these data I will build some panels, one for each object.

I have a list of customers, and each customers has a specific name and color:

```
$scope.customers = [{ 
    "samsung": [
        { "color": "#fcd5b4", "logo": 'img/samsug.png' },
    ],
    "htc": [
        { "color": "#ff66ff", "logo": 'img/htc.png' },
    ],
    "hp": [
        { "color": "#acd5b4", "logo": 'img/hp.png' },
    ]
}];
```

In the HTML I should write:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers" style="background-color: {{customer.samsung.color}}">
    <table><tbody>
        <tr><td class="logo">
            <img src="{{customer.samsung.logo}}">       
        </td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

But later I will not know the names of customers.

How can I repeat all elements without knowing the name of customers?

Comment: Blessed are you who are already geniuses.

Comment: You need to use the customers as dictionary like this: ng-repeat="(key,value) in customers[0]"

Comment: Your question is not very clear and you seem to have an unmatched `{` and commas where there shouldn't be.

Comment: where commas shouldn't be?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/22493/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to get `(key,value)` pair in `ng-repeat`. I hope and thought this is exactly match your context. You have some array confusion in your code what should be repeat in the html part.

Script - you missed flower brace in the end

```
  $scope.customers = [
{ 
    "samsung": [
        {
            "color": "#fcd5b4", "logo": 'img/samsug.png', "numbers":[{"number": 123}, {"number": 938103}, {"number": 93810}]
        },
    ],

    "htc": [
        {
            "color": "#ff66ff", "logo": 'img/htc.png' ,"numbers":[{"number": 6341}, {"number": 345134}, {"number": 345134}]
        },
    ],

    "hp": [
        {
            "color": "#acd5b4", "logo": 'img/hp.png' ,"numbers":[{"number": 1346}, {"number": 613461}, {"number": 77134}]
        },
    ]
    }
];
```

And your code be

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in customers[0]" style="background-color: {{value[0].color}}">
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="logo">
        <img ng-src="{{value[0].logo}}">  
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="(keynum, valuenum) in value[0].numbers">{{valuenum.number}}</li>
        </ul>
    </td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/22493/)

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to inset a subarray and repeat it in a list. But doesn't work, why? Look the upadte of your fiddle

Comment: I didn't get your point. I coded as per your json structure you given in the question. Now you told " inset a subarray and repeat it in a list. But doesn't work" I didn't understood what you trying to say

Comment: yes I found it you have issue in your json structure also missed the flower braces in the end. can you look at that in my updated code

Comment: @panagulis72 - yes wait i will look on your fiddle

Comment: your current json structure is totally collapsed

Comment: lol!!!!!! Thank you very very very much, you have been very helpful and patient , especially with a person who has been studying recently angular and json

Answer (score 0):

```
style="background-color: {{customer.color}}"
```

and

```
<img ng-src="{{customer.logo}}">
```

this should do it.

Your customer is the current element of your array...

Comment: Might be, but I don't think this was the question

Comment: It will prevent a 404 error because the browser will try to fetch the literal text (`{{customer.logo}}`) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc . Please change it to `ng-src` and i'll upvote this answer

Comment: I've edited as you suggest, but it doesn't work yet https://jsbin.com/ruxeheboja/